# A problem about generating random integers

Tags: probability

I have an generator which can generate a series of ideal random integers in range [1,N]. Asymptotically, I want to prove

(1)The average number of integers before the first duplicated integer is $\sqrt{\pi N/2}$.

(2)The average number of integers needed to generate before containing all [1,N] is NlogN.

This can be verified by programming, but I want to prove it using probability and analysis.

The second is exactly the coupon collector problem, and I have understand the solution. But for the first one, I get the following sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{k^2(N-1)!}{N^k(N-k)!}$$
But I can't figure out its asymptotic property.

Comment: The first problem is called the birthday paradox. The second is called the coupon collector.

Comment: Well, where can I find related materials

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

**(1)** If you pick 1 number, there is no duplicate. If you pick 2, then the probability of picking a repeated one is $1/N$. If you've picked 2 different numbers then the chance of picking a repeated one on the third pick is $2/N$ (but you had a $(N-1)/N$ probability of getting here). Now continue this reasoning and computed the expected number of picks until a repeated one.

**(2)** You have $N!$ ways of getting all $[1,..,N]$ numbers with $N$ picks, while you had $N^N$ possible first $N$ picks. To get all numbers with $N+1$ picks you had $(N+1)!/2$ ways out of $N^{N+1}$. Can you also continue the reasoning and compute the expectation from here?

Also notice that you can't actually verify this with programming. You can design a Monte-Carlo test that will *estimate* theses probabilities, and you'll have a result within a confidence interval (which is hard to refine). And this result may be close to, but would never be exactly $\sqrt{\pi N/2}$ for instance. However, such tests are very good to help dismiss an erroneous result.

Comment: Using probability I find the sum very complicated, so the critical problem for me may be how to use analysis to get the asymptotic result.

Comment: Consider editing your question to show some work, so that people here may understand what is troubling you, then more hints may arise =)